# The convergence of the Fresnel integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that the Fresnel integral essentially converges conditionally.

I managed to work on it and showed that:
$$
\int\limits_0^x \sin(t^2) \, dt = 
\sum_{n=0}^\infty
\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!(4n+3)}x^{4n+3}
$$

when $x=1$, it can be proved that the series converges.

as $x\to\infty$ I am not sure what to really do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^x\sin t^2\,dt=\frac{1-\cos x^2}{2x}+\int_0^x\frac{1-\cos t^2}{2t^2}\,dt$$ (integration by parts), after which everything should be clear.

Comment: I applied it and got $=-\dfrac{\cos\left(t^2\right)-1}{t}-{\displaystyle\int}2\sin\left(t^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}t$ how is this useful?

Comment: the limit of the first term in RHS is $0$ but what would the limit of the integral be?

Comment: @deerclaysup: the 1st term on the RHS of my equality tends to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, the 2nd clearly has a finite limit (the $\int_0^\infty$ converges *absolutely*).

Comment: are you sure absolutely?  I think you meant conditionally

Comment: @deerclaysup: Yes, I am. $(1-\cos t^2)/(2t^2)$ is nonnegative, and bounded by $1/t^2$ for $t$ away from $0$.